# RxSwift: Observing changes to items stored in an array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I've just started looking at RxSwift and am a beginner.  Is there a way to observe changes to individual elements within an array?  I have an object that stores an array of Item objects and I would like to be notified when any of the properties of the Item objects change.  So far I have this:

```
struct Item {
  var dayOfTheWeek = Variable<Int>(1)

  init(dayOfTheWeek: Int) {
    self.dayOfTheWeek.value = dayOfTheWeek
  }
}

class ItemListener {
  var items = Variable<[Item]>([])
  var itemsUpdated: Observable<[Item]>

  init() {
    self.itemsUpdated = items.asObservable()
  }

  func queue(item: Item) {
    self.items.value.append(item)

    self.itemsUpdated.subscribe(onNext: {
        $0.forEach{
            print("dayOfTheWeek \($0.dayOfTheWeek.value)")
        }
    })
  }
}
```

If I then do this

```
let itemListener = ItemListener()
var item = Item(dayOfTheWeek: 5)
itemListener.queue(item: item)
```

It will observe any items added to the array.  Once an item has been added to the array, how would I observe changes to the state of each item *in* the array?  If I update the dayOfTheWeek on the item in the array, how would ItemListener get this notification that the dayOfTheWeek changed on the item?

```
item.dayOfTheWeek = 2  // ItemListener wants to get notified of this update
```

Comment: Why do you subscribe each time you queue up an item?